# Using a transistor to control a pull-down switch

Tags: transistors, pulldown

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSu9qM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a Runcam 2 video camera.  It uses a temporary switch to turn on/off and start/stop recording.  I would like to control these functions with an arduino.  Once side of the switch is 3V the other is ground.  Pushing the switch pulls the 3V to ground.  I've soldered two wires to the switch and can operate the camera by shorting the two wires.  I would like to use an NPN transistor with the base controlled by an arduino pin or other suitable method to operate the camera.  I've searched the archives and the closest I found was using a transistor to pull a pin low.  It did not help.  I am limited in my electronics knowledge and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific than "It did not help". Draw us a schematic of what you tried and describe what you observed.

Comment: There is a schematic drawing tool button on the editor toolbar. It has all you need to draw a schematic. Double-click components to edit their properties.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question to show a schematic (not a block diagram or wiring diagram). The schematic editor here is a breeze to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: How do you get to the editor toolbar?

Comment: It is now working and I have attached a schematic of my current configuration.

Comment: Your transistor is backwards FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Q1's emitter and collector swapped. It *might* work in that configuration but it's not the right or most reliable way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVMQZM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. NPN transistor ORed with internal switch.*

I've redrawn the circuit in a more conventional fashion. Positive voltages are to the top, grounds at the bottom and logical control flow from left to right.

The camera will have a pull-up resistor on the input and SW1 pulls it to ground. Your Q1 will do the same thing.

Comment: The comment instructions say not to say "Thanks", so I will say that I appreciate your help.  I did have the transistor emitter and collector swapped as you and one other pointed out.  I have that fixed now.  I also appreciate the guidance on proper representation of circuits.

Comment: Thanks. Give it a day or two. If no better answers come you can accept mine. You can upvote any answers that are useful.